# Flip line only on selected rows with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and calculate new line bearing on it

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, linestring

I'm trying to use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to flip line only on selected records in shapefile that are greater than value 180. Then I would like to recalculate Line Bearing on the attribute called "azimut" again only on the values that are greater than 180.

So far I´ve tried this code but i think the flip was applied on every row:

```
#Select line with azimut greater than 180 and recalculate new line bearing values on it

counter = 1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_edge, ['azimut','Shape@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] > 180:
            arcpy.edit.FlipLine(row[1])
            print("updated: ", counter)
            counter += 1
        cursor.updateRow(row)

# Calculate the bearing of the flipped line

arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_edge, "azimut", "!SHAPE.bearing!","PYTHON3", "!SHAPE.angle! > 180")
```

Another solution also failed:

```
# Create the cursor

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Roads", ["SHAPE@"], "!SHAPE.angle! > 180")


# Iterate through the rows and flip the line

for row in cursor:

    arcpy.FlipLine_edit(row[0])

    cursor.updateRow(row)


# Delete the cursor

del cursor
```

Comment: You have two different problems here. In the first your indentation is off. In the second you use the CalculateField syntax for the `where_clause`. Neither code block attempts to recalculate the angle.

Comment: Have you searched the ESRI forum? This was the [first return](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/flip-subset-of-lines-using-arcpy-flipline-edit-in/m-p/424686#M33342)...